# Add object works with logic brinks but cannot figure out the scripting

Tags: scripting

I am making tic tac toe using cubes and spheres rather than Xs and Os. I have 9 empties corresponding to the spaces on the 3 x 3 grid. I can make it work using logic brick, but not with py script. The cubes and spheres only appear at the coordinates where the sample objects are on the inactive scene layer. I have tried everything I can think of.

```
import bge

def main():

    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    player = cont.owner
    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

    key1 = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.ONEKEY]
    key2 = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.TWOKEY]

    pad3 = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.PAD3]
    pad4 = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.PAD4]

    # objects = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects
    # object_cube = objects["Cube"]
    # object_sphere = objects["Sphere"]   ### no error code but breaks the game

    if key1:
        player.scene.addObject('Cube')
        # position = mathutils.Vector([5, 5, 0]) ### all things I've tried
        # gameObject.worldPosition('Cube') = position
        # addObject.worldPosition = [5, 5, 0]     
        # Cube.worldPosition = [5, 5, 0]
        # player.scene.addObject.worldPosition = [5, 5, 0]

    elif key2:
        player.scene.addObject('Sphere')        

    elif pad3:
        player.scene.addObject('Cube')

    elif pad4:
        player.scene.addObject('Sphere')
```

main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the obj.worldPosition after added it. And your script look wrong... player.scene.addObject.worldPosition make no sense how you try it. xD

```
from bge import logic

spwnPoint = scene.objects['Empty'] 
keysensor = logic.getCurrentController().sensors['SpacebarKey']
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
_cube = scene.objectsInactive['Cube']

if keysensor.positive:
    addedobj = scene.addObject(_cube)
    addedobj.worldPosition = spwnPoint.worldPosition
```

[image]

You need to use a keyboard sensor to trigger the script and be able to add an object once a key is pressed, or put and always sensor to true triggering level and you will be able to use `key1 = bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.ONEKEY]` but this way the script will add an nonsense amount of objects related to the frame rate because the script will run every frame and if u press a key for lets say 1 sec. if the project frame rate is set to 60 you will get 60 objects.

Comment: Thank you Strapicarus. I got it to work as shown. Before I go ahead and finish it, I'm going to see if I can add some more variables to reduce the amount of lines of code I'm using.

Comment: (sorry for bad formatting) scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
spwnPoint1 = scene.objects['Empty1'] 
spwnPoint2 = scene.objects['Empty2'] 
keysensor1 = bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors['Numpad1']
keysensor2 = bge.logic.getCurrentController().sensors['Numpad2']
_cube = scene.objectsInactive['Cube']

def main():
    if keysensor1.positive:
        addedobj = scene.addObject(_cube)
        addedobj.worldPosition = spwnPoint1.worldPosition
        
    if keysensor2.positive:
        addedobj = scene.addObject(_cube)
        addedobj.worldPosition = spwnPoint2.worldPosition

Comment: Looks ok... next time use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/89416/edit) link under the question to add or edit info. dont put code in the comments is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about game engine but you can simply set the location of an object in a regular scene.

```
object.location = Vector([1,2,3])
```